# Python boto3 lambda error: 'Organizations' object has no attribute 'list_tags_for_resource'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am developing a lamdba function to execute a python boto3 script that lists out all of my AWS accounts and tags.

I've tried doing this locally and it works fine (both listing accounts and tags).  When I deploy it as a lambda running in python 3.6 (I am running python 3.6.5 locally), even the listing of accounts work fine, but it's the tags that won't list.  I am using this API call:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_tags_for_resource

```
import re
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cross_account_role = 'my-uber-admin-role'
    client = boto3.client('sts')
    current = client.get_caller_identity()
    user_id = re.sub('[:;+&<>?(){}!#$%^|]','-',current['UserId'])
    account = '<redacted_master_payer_account>'
    role_session_name = '{}-{}'.format(account, user_id)[:64]
    role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::{}:role/{}'.format(account, cross_account_role)
    response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName=role_session_name, DurationSeconds=900)
    access_key = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    secret_key = response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    session_token = response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    orgClient = boto3.client('organizations', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, aws_session_token=session_token)

    # works in my lambda and locally - list accounts
    output = []
    paginator = orgClient.get_paginator('list_accounts').paginate(PaginationConfig={'MaxResults': 20})
    for page in paginator:
        output = output + page['Accounts']
    acct_ids = [account['Id'] for account in output]
    print(acct_ids)

    # given a list of accounts, return dict of accts and tags
    # works locally, but not in my lambda
    orgClient2 = boto3.client('organizations', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, aws_session_token=session_token)
    payload = []
    for id in acct_ids:
        tags = orgClient2.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceId=id)['Tags']
        payload.append({'account_id': id, 'tags': tags})
    print(payload)


    return 'foo'
```

Output:

```
START RequestId: b1321ca7-0219-4e3e-9e21-78616fbee573 Version: $LATEST
['1234567', '12345678', '123456789']
'Organizations' object has no attribute 'list_tags_for_resource': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/run.py", line 35, in lambda_handler
    tags = orgClient2.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceId=id)['Tags']
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 555, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'Organizations' object has no attribute 'list_tags_for_resource'
```

I would expect this statement:

```
    orgClient2.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceId=id)['Tags']
```

to work just swimmingly.  What am I missing?

Comment: if @vikyol is correct, then you have to refer [THIS](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.7.74/reference/services/organizations.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using default [Python 3.6 runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for Lambda, which uses boto3-1.7.74 and botocore-1.10.74.
The API version you are referring to is boto3-1.9.212.

To solve this issue, you can create either a deployment package or a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) containing the correct versions  of boto3 and botocore.